# Длина строки переменной javascript

Tags: javascript, строки

Каков теоретический предел символов в строке?
У меня планируется строчка длиной 5 миллионов символов, не споткнется ли интерпретатор о такую строчку?

Comment: проверил. кушает длинные строки без потерь и быстро :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретический предел диктуется аллокатором и разрядностью. Практический же предел диктуется тем, что клиент может огорчиться, если приложение попытается выделить 100G памяти :) 5 миллионов символов это грубо говоря 10 мегабайт памяти. Что это такое в наши времена?

Единственная опасность может вас поджидать, если вы собираетесь эту строку формировать по одному символу - такое скорее всего будет работать ОЧЕНЬ медленно, так ему придётся при каждом прибавлении символа к строке создавать новую строку, копировать в неё старую, а потом приписывать символ. Это жутко неэффективно и может заставить GC понервничать, если делать так слишком часто.

Comment: благодарю за ответ. поэтому я парсер хочу вытянуть на сторону клиента - на сервере он затыкался и в итоге сервер выдавал ошибку.

Comment: Оо... если сервер затыкается... то дело плохо.. вы уверены, что клиент в принципе может это выполнить? Или может на сервере сделано очень неэффективно?

Comment: сервер затыкается, поскольку настройки хостинга через 90 секунд дают отвал по тайм-ауту. я переписал пхп-скрипт, оставил только получение данных без парсинга. 3млн символов вернулось через 10 сек, это отлично. теперь ваяю на жабаскрипте парсер.

Answer (score 2):

Как пишут на [многих форумах](http://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&q=javascript+string+maximum+length), максимальная длина не установлена стандартами. Но рекомендуется не ставить более мегабайта.
А зачем вам 5М символов? Может есть обходные пути?

Comment: некий сервер отдает в текстовом виде данные от охранных датчиков, период просмотра таких ответов может быть очень немаленьким. ответ этот я буду парсить.

Comment: А почему бы вам не парсить все php? А просмотр результатов сделать с помощью ajax.

Comment: php не успевает. поначалу я парсинг на сервере выполнял, запрашивая через аякс, но на обработке больщих запросов по таймауту скрипт отваливается.

Comment: А если попробовать curl'ом получать данные и писать их в файл? А потом запускать второй скрипт - парсер. Получится что-то вроде разделения задачи и парсер может успеть. Или договоритесь с программистами, чтобы сервер выдавал лишь те данные, которые нужны в конкретный момент (по get-запросу или типа того).